# Is rethinkdb suitable for a chat application

Tags: rethinkdb

I saw that rethinkdb has real-time capabilities which made me think it would be great for a chat application - however I saw the caveat in the rethink website that says apps requiring high write throughput should consider riak instead.

What is this limit for write that it is mentioning, and is it still suitable for a standard chat application that would support many thousands of concurrent users?

Comment: 1. You are rude, this is a question tagged for rethinkdb, and if you don't have experience with it you should refrain from commenting  2. you need a database or some sort of datastore to persist  chat state unless you only want something in memory 3. not re-inventing the wheel, merely pulling off the shelf components to put together a chat app that fits custom requirements,  implementing the app to data store is trivial.  4. this is very specifically a question about rethink write thoroughput with a use case example

Comment: Why not ejabberd + riak?

Comment: have a bunch of credits with an existing rethink vendor and don't necessarily need the xmpp support... so was more curious about learning more about rethinkdb since it's a new technology.  I know it can be done in other ways, but wanted to explore rethink's capabilities.

Comment: I don't think that you will have any problems with Rethink. But anyway, if you will have performance issues, you can always use some sort of cache: memcache, Redis, etc to reduce load on rethink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RethinkDB is a good choice for a chat application. In fact, its [realtime changefeeds](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/) are specifically designed to make it easy to build these kinds of realtime applications.

The FAQ actually states:

> In some cases RethinkDB trades off write availability in favor of data consistency. If high write availability is critical and you don’t mind dealing with conflicts you may be better off with a Dynamo-style system like Riak.

Write availability is not the same as write throughput. RethinkDB's write throughput is more than capable of handling thousands of concurrent users (most databases will do fine in this respect).

Regarding write availability: RethinkDB favors consistency, whereas Riak favors availability. This set of tradeoffs is commonly referred to as the CAP theorem, which states that in one distributed system it is impossible to achieve all three properies: consistency, availability, and partition tolerance.

You can read more about what this means in the [RethinkDB architecture FAQ](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/architecture/#cap-theorem).